# Exclude a QuerySet from a QuerySet in many to many relationship

Tags: django, database

I have these models:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)

class Pack(models.Model):
    pack_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, default='Repository')
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)
    number_of_words = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have several Pack within which there are several words added. I want to make a list of all words except ones that are added inside a specific Pack, namely "Others"; i.e. I want do something like this:

```
otherPackModel = Pack.objects.get(pack_name="Others")
wordModels = Word.objects.all().exclude(otherPackModel.words)
wordlist = wordModels.values_list('word', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Word.objects.filter(pack__pack_name="some name").exclude(pack__pack_name="others").values('word',flat=True)
```

I am using [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) between `Word` and `Pack` model to make this query.

Comment: Each word can be a member of several packs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `Word` objects that do not have any relation with any `Pack` object you can use a queryset like following:

```
words_list = Word.objects.exclude(pack_set__isnull=False).values_list('word', flat=True) # or words_list = Word.objects.filter(pack_set__isnull=True).values_list('word', flat=True)
```

Note: `pack_set` in queryset is your default related query name, so don't forget to change this to your related name if you change this related name in your model's field.
But if you want to list all the `Word` objects that is not shared by specific `Pack` object (or group of `Pack` objects) you can use following codes:

One pack object:

```
otherPackModel = Pack.objects.get(pack_name="Others")
wordModels = Word.objects.exclude(pack_set=otherPackModel)
wordlist = wordModels.values_list('word', flat=True)
```

Group of pack objects:

```
otherPackModel = Pack.objects.filter(pack_name="some random name")
wordModels = Word.objects.exclude(pack_set__in=otherPackModel)
wordlist = wordModels.values_list('word', flat=True)
```